# Laravel HTML Dropdown does not remember selected values

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

there is very strange situation with Laravel generating drop-down menu.

I am trying to generate a multiple drop-down menu using the Semantic-UI, the problem comes when the form is not validated and it does not remember the selected values.

The code is pretty simple:

```
$selected_currencies = ($brand->currency != '') ? explode(', ', $brand->currency) : [];
{!! Form::select('currency[]', $currencies, $selected_currencies, ['class' => 'ui fluid dropdown', 'multiple']) !!}
```

Instead of "[]" i have tried with "null" and "''", but id does not save the chosen values.

The most strange for me is, that I have two websites using similar form. On localhost both forms does not work as i wish. Each website is placed on different hosting and one of them is showing the saved values as it should.

So i am wondering if this is possible of the PHP Version or any other setting ?

Comment: before passing it to form try {{ $selected_currencies  }} to check what it contains, even it is returning an array or not

Comment: The first row can be simplified using explicit cast : `{!! Form::select('currency[]', $currencies, (array) $selected_currencies, /* ...* /) !!}`

Comment: @Exprator it returns me an empty array, but if the array is empty normally the Form will get old('currency') and will display the entered values. But it does not display anything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the Laravelcollection plugin, see here:
https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/commit/3dcf2185a1a329e6c19bb1eaa89de9cf91572145

Unfortunately i need to use it like that:

```
return in_array($value, $selected) ? 'selected' : null;
```